# Meteor Mongodb deep searching

Tags: node.js, mongodb, search, meteor

I am trying to achieve the best possible way to search between different collections.
Here is a simple scenario:

Just like WhatsApp, I want to search the chats.

Here is a very simple criteria I just created:

I have 2 collections:

- Users
- Chattings

**Users:**

```
[
    {
        "_id": "Xuibgsadbgsi35Gsdf",
        "fullName": "User A"
    },
    {
        "_id": "Afstg34tg4536gh",
        "fullName": "User B"
    },
    {
        "_id": "KHJDFhfs7dfgsvdfwsef",
        "fullName": "User C"
    }
]
```

**Chatting:**

```
[
    {
        "_id": "Phsdfyg92345sgb7651",
        "title": "Group 1",
        "chatType": "groupChatting"
    },
    {
        "_id": "YONgsa793423bD",
        "title": "All users group",
        "chatType": "groupChatting"
    },
    {
        "_id": "Uysdf345GBHsdf",
        "chatType": "oneToOneChatting",
        "ownerUserId": "Afstg34tg4536gh",
        "chatWithUserId" "Xuibgsadbgsi35Gsdf"
    },
    {
        "_id": "Fbgu283gbnap023656",
        "chatType": "oneToOneChatting",
        "ownerUserId": "KHJDFhfs7dfgsvdfwsef",
        "chatWithUserId" "Afstg34tg4536gh"
    },
    {
        "_id": "Ong7gAUDSFg7235ng",
        "title": "Group 2",
        "chatType": "groupChatting"
    }
]
```

Here is my query:
`Chatting.find({"title": {$regex : ".*user.*", $options: 'i' }}).fetch();`

Now the expected result here is:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "YONgsa793423bD",
        "title": "All users group",
        "chatType": "groupChatting"
    },
    {
        "_id": "Uysdf345GBHsdf",
        "chatType": "oneToOneChatting",
        "ownerUserId": "Afstg34tg4536gh",
        "chatWithUserId" "Xuibgsadbgsi35Gsdf"
    },
    {
        "_id": "Fbgu283gbnap023656",
        "chatType": "oneToOneChatting",
        "ownerUserId": "KHJDFhfs7dfgsvdfwsef",
        "chatWithUserId" "Afstg34tg4536gh"
    }
]
```

Now here you can see that I wont get any results, because I have Users in other collections but technically from App User perspective, he should see the chats:

- Uysdf345GBHsdf
- Fbgu283gbnap023656

Now in my mind I can do something like, I first search those users with searchText: `User`, and then collect all those `_id` from `Users` collection in array and match in `Chatting` collection, but this seems way too bad...

So can anyone tell me what is the best possible way to achieve such scenario?

Comment: Your example contains not `type` field, which is used in your query.

Comment: @Jankapunkt sorry its a typo, type == title

Comment: To be frank, I don't really understand what you need to do. Theoretically, what do you need as a result? Your queries (as a concept) and your content don't seem to work together hence I am not sure what is the expectation of your final result.

Moreover, "oneToOneChatting" can be easily written "otoc" or something short. Same for "groupChatting", the point being that it makes your regex queries and queries in general much faster considering that your will possibly have hundreeds of users with many thousands of conversations and messages.

Comment: @PaulPaulincai In WhatsApp you see group chatting & one to one chatting on single screen mixed up.. when you search and type user, it will search through both groups and one to one chattings, In my case I store both groups and one to one chatting in single collection i.e Chatting. Now in one to one chatting, I store only sender and receiverId in record, not those users actual names, so how can I search some user in Chatting collection, if that user fullName is stored in Users collection

Comment: @StormTrooper now it is clear. I think I and others got lost at "Now the expected result here is" which was not actually what you expected/wanted.

There are 2 possible ways to do this. Store the ownerUser as an object { userId: ...., fullName: ... }. For a user you will have .... up to 1000 chats?! In this case you can run a method to update fullName on all chats if the user changes name. This was done before by some, you can find it in the Meteor forum and this is the most "old Mongo" way.
The second way is to implement https://github.com/cult-of-coders/grapher which is what I have done.